# MouseListener not triggering

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have been working on this code for long and going back and forth with mouse events. I have a `MainClass` (implements `MouseListener`). The UI has a `JFrame` which has a `basePanel`. The `BasePanel` has `GridPanel` (call Grid implements `MouseListener`). The `Grid` has individual `JPanel` on `GridLayout`. When I click on `Grid` it triggers the event methods in `Grid` but not in `MainClass`. It used to work earlier but not any more.

In the interface methods I have entered just println to tracks what's triggering.

MAINCLASS

```
public class PlayConnect implements MouseListener{

private JFrame mainFrame;
private JPanel basePanel,
buttonPanel,
messagePanel;

private Grid gridPanel;

private void startGame(){

    mainFrame = new JFrame("Connect-4");
    mainFrame.setSize(800, 700);    

    basePanel = new JPanel();
    basePanel.setName("basePanel");
    mainFrame.add(basePanel);

    gridPanel = new Grid();
    gridPanel.addMouseListener(this); //Added MouseListner
    gridPanel.setName("GridPanel");


    basePanel.add(gridPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    messagePanel = new JPanel();
    //      messagePanel.addMouseListener(this);
    messagePanel.setName("messagePanel");

    messArea = new JTextArea();
    messArea.setEditable(false);
    messFont = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 20);
    messArea.setFont(messFont);
    messArea.setText("Game On !");

    messagePanel.add(messArea);
    basePanel.add(messagePanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setName("button Panel");
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


    randButton = new JButton("Random Moves");
    buttonPanel.add(randButton);
    randButtonHandle = new RandomMoves();
    randButton.addActionListener(randButtonHandle);
    basePanel.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.LINE_END);


    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}
```

`Grid` Class

```
public class Grid extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

private Cell[][] gridUI = new Cell[6][7];
private static int[][] gridTrack = new int[6][7];
private static int player = 1;
private static Boolean gameOver = false;
public Boolean randPlayer;
private static ArrayList<Cell> cellArray = new ArrayList<Cell>();

public Grid(){
    //      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,700));;
    setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 7));
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            Cell tempCell = new Cell(i,j);
            tempCell.addMouseListener(this);
            gridUI[i][j] = tempCell;
            gridTrack[i][j] = 0;
            add(tempCell);

            int index = i*6 + j;
            cellArray.add(tempCell);

        }

    }
    addMouseListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how event processing in Swing works.  From a very high-level view - when an event is generated, the topmost component at that coordinate is checked to see if it will consume the event.  If so, the event is delivered to that component and processing stops; if not, the next-topmost component at that location is checked, and so on until you reach the top-level container.  An event will never be delivered to more than one component.

If you really need your top-level container to get all events, even on children with registered listeners, you can do so by using an AWTEventListener, or by using a GlassPane and handling re-dispatching the event yourself, both as described in [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186333/how-can-i-capture-all-mouse-events-in-a-jframe-swing).

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it. Just to make sure we are on same page when I have a Frame which has a Panel (P1) and that has Panel P2, you would refer to Frame as top level container I suppose? Let me know if you meant other way around.

Comment: Yeah, by "top-level container" I meant the Frame or Window.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed my approach and made my classes talk via methods instead of sharing events. The reason was I needed one event to be shared but not all of them and it was getting out of control with all empty methods just sitting there. I even considered using observer classes but that was bit of overkill. Thanks anyways! I did learn about events through your post and links !