# Attached Listener to every components of an Swing application

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a library that will dump every click of a user session. I am looking for a way to attached to listener to every component will be instanciate in Swing. I need to add those listeners from a single entry point (meaning that creating factories for every components or similar option are not possible).
For the moment I am able to attached a listener to every **already instanciate** components using the following snippet :

```
public void addClickListenerToAllComponents(){
   for(Container container : Frame.getFrames()){
       recursivelyAddClickToComponent(container);
   }
}
```

I could create a Thread that recall this snippet every seconds, but that could add some load or create timing issues. Would there be a way to add listener to every components that **would be instanciate** in the future ?

Comment: No need to add a listener to every component. You can use an `AWTEventListener`. See: [How can I capture all mouse events in a JFrame/Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186522/131872)

Comment: AWTEventListener is too low level, I would like to use DocumentListener or ComponentAdapter for recording typing or resizing.

Comment: (1-) *I would like to use DocumentListener or ComponentAdapter for recording typing or resizing.* - your question states: `I am writing a library that will dump every click of a user session`. Your code is adding "ClickToComponent". What do a DocumentListener and and ComponentListener have to do with a "click". How can we answer a question if you keep changing the requirements. Also, why do you think you can't listen for KeyEvents and ComponentEvents from the AWTEventListener? Post a proper [mre] demonstrating your requirement since you question is not clear/complete.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/ContainerListener.html. Add an instance to each container. If `componentAdded` is called, attach both of your listeners to the newly added component recursively. If `componentRemoved` is called, it's polite to remove both of your listeners from the newly removed component recursively.